# How to implement SQL case statement in ElasticSearch - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have to implement SQL like Case When statement in rails-4 ElasticSearch. I have been searching for related topics since some days, but not able to achieve any proper document that can help me out with this.

My SQL condition which has to be implemented in ElasticSearch looks like this:

```
status_id=? and active=? and (((start_date >= ?) and (start_date <= ?)) or ((start_date <= ?) and (end_date >= ?) and ("
CASE WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Sat') THEN '#{Date.parse("sat")}' >= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Fri') THEN '#{Date.parse("fri")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Thu') THEN '#{Date.parse("thu")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Wed') THEN '#{Date.parse("wed")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Tue') THEN '#{Date.parse("tue")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Mon') THEN '#{Date.parse("mon")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
  WHEN (array_to_string(event_active_days, ', ') like '%Sun') THEN '#{Date.parse("sun")}'>= '#{range_start_date}'
END)))
```

As if now, mine ElasticSearch query is as follows:

```
search_query = {
    query: {
      wildcard: { 
        _all: keywords
      }
    }, 
    filter: {
      query: {
        query_string: {
          query: "status_id:2 AND active:true AND 
          ((start_date:>=#{range_start_date} AND start_date:<=#{range_end_date}) (start_date:<=#{range_start_date} AND end_date:>=#{range_start_date}))"
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

This is where i have to implement sql like case-when statement in elasticsearch.

Can someone please help me with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your document/mapping look like? Anyway, that's something you should do at indexing time, i.e. you should extract the day from your `event_active_days` field and index it in a new field that you can easily query at search time.

Comment: Right now i have done the default indexing, ie., `Model.import`. How can i map additional fields to the document for each record through code? Can u suggest any link that can help me with this.

Comment: or you can use script score function to implement case statement in sandboxed script and set min_score value to filter them off.